# Regular Expression Pattern Matching

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I need to do like this.

```
Actually **ctu** is a good university but **ctu's** is not. There are many **,ctus,** present.
```

What I want to do is, I want to replace ctu in the string like this.

```
Actually **<s>ctu<e>** is a good university but **<s>ctu's<e>** is not. There are many **,<s>ctus<e>,** present.
```

But with the following pattern

```
**\\bctu*(?:['\\\\|""\\\\]*)\\w+\\b**
```

I'm getting the out put as:

```
A**<s>ctu<e>**ally **<s>ctu<e>** is a good university but **<s>ctu's<e>** is not. There are many **,ctus,**   present.
```

**I dont want to replace ctu inside words Actually. and also I need to replace `" ,ctus, "` with `" ,<s>ctus<e>, "`**
How do I achieve this using regex. I need this in c#. csharp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I need to replace " ,ctus, " with " ,ctus, "": what is difference between those ??

Comment: @Tigran, check it again after some code formatting :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex matches all the cases listed in your example:

```
@"(\bctu(?:'\w+)?\w*\b)"
```

Then just replace the match with `@"<s>\1<e>"` where `\1` is the backreference to the match above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `@"\bctu\b"` ("ctu" with word boundaries on both sides, so it matches `ctu` but not `Actually`, `ctu's`, or `,ctus,`) for the first search pattern and `",ctus,"` (exactly the string `,ctus,`, regardless of where it might fall in a word) as the second search pattern?  To search for both of these at once, you could use `@"(\bctu\b|,ctus,)"`.

As a slight aside, in C# you can write regex literals much easier by using the `@""` notation ([verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)) instead of `""`.  E.g. to get regex to understand a word boundary, it must see `\b`, which can be represented as `@"\b"` or `"\\b"`, and a literal `\` is `"\\\\"` or `@"\\"`.  The first is easier to read, especially in more complex cases.

If this doesn't answer your question, please give a clear example of expected input/output.

Comment: `\bctu\b` does (partly) match `ctu's` because there is a word boundary between `u` and `'`.